# como hacer una ventana que muestre el Texto (grande) de mi tabla

Tags: html, css, tablas

Estoy haciendo una tabla que muestra lo que hay en la base de datos, tengo que 2 mediumtext que al visualizarse adentro de la tabla, se agranda muchísimo, necesito saber como con js/ajax y css podría hacer esta ventana y que muestre el contenido completo este es mi codigo:

```
<?php 
include('con_db.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mostrarDatos.css">
</head>
<body>

    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Texto1</th>
      <th>Texto2</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

   <?php 
        
        $verSql = "SELECT * from usuarios";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $verSql);
        
       ?>
   <?php 
  while ($verDatos = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      
      ?>

    <tr class="tabla">
      <td><strong><?php echo $verDatos['id'];?></strong></td>
      <td><?php echo $verDatos['nombre']; ?></td>
      <td  class="flex1"><?php echo $verDatos['texto1']; ?></td>
      <td  class="flex2"><?php echo $verDatos['texto2']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $verDatos['fecha']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    

<div class="muestraTexto1">

  <p><?php echo $verDatos['texto1'];?></p>

</div>

<div class="muestraTexto2">

  <p><?php echo $verDatos['texto2'];?></p>

</div>

    

    
  <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="js/mostrarDatos.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

// js //

```
let texto1 = document.querySelector('.flex1');

texto1.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    
     
   document.querySelector('.muestraTexto1').style.display = 'block';
   
});



let texto2 = document.querySelector('.flex2');



texto2.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    
     
   document.querySelector('.muestraTexto2').style.display = 'block';
   
});
```

// CSS

```
.muestraTexto1{
    display: none;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;

}

.muestraTexto2{
    display: none;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;

}
```

Me abre los solo los textos de el primer dato o sea ID: 1 , no se como trasmitirlo a los otros elementos que se generan con el bucle de en php, busque un montón y no encuentro esto, tendría que usar si o si Ajax?
perdón por mi ignorancia

Comment: Quieres hacerlo como una ventana modal?

Comment: exactamentee!!!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer que al principio se muestren el texto1 y texto2 con puntos suspensivos, dándole el estilo de la clase .flex a ambos `<div>` que dejé en los `<td>`.

- PHP/HTML

```html
 <!-- VENTANA MODAL INVISIBLE -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id="muestra_texto">
     <!-- aqui se cargará el texto completo --> 
    </p>

  </div>

</div>



...
<td >
 <div id="texto1" class="flex" onclick="abre_modal(this.id)"><?php echo $verDatos['texto1']; ?></div>
</td>

<td>
 <div id="texto2" class="flex" onclick="abre_modal(this.id)"><?php echo $verDatos['texto2']; ?></div>
</td>
...
```

- CSS

```css
.flex {
       width: 230px;
       white-space: nowrap;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;
       overflow: hidden; 
}
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

- JS

```
// Obtiene el modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

function abre_modal(id){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("muestra_texto").innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).textContent;
}

// obtiene el <span> que cierra el modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


// Cuando clickees en el <span> (x), cerrará el modal y limpiara muestra_texto
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("muestra_texto").innerHTML ="";
}

// Cuando clickees fuera del modal, se cerrará y se limpiara el muestra_texto
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("muestra_texto").innerHTML ="";
  }
}
```

Entonces con el `onclick` que le dejé, podrás abrir el modal cargando el texto de los `td` en el mismo modal.

Apliqué lo de este enlace https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp